# What kind of pine code statements can be used to test the following specific time frames on trading view charts

Tags: time, pine-script, resolution

With Pine code, How do i test to see if the current chart time frame is between **4Hrs and 11Hrs** or if the time frame is between **12Hrs and 4days**?

What i tried:

```
IsHourlyTF2() =>
    timeframe.isminutes and (timeframe.multiplier >= 240 or timeframe.multiplier < 660)

IsDailyTF() =>
    timeframe.isminutes and (timeframe.multiplier >= 720 or timeframe.multiplier < 5760)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `timeframe.in_seconds()` variable. These will return true or false depending on if the chart time frame falls between 4 and 11 hours or 12 hours and 4 day.

```
tf411 = timeframe.in_seconds() >= timeframe.in_seconds('240') and timeframe.in_seconds() <= timeframe.in_seconds('660')
tf124 = timeframe.in_seconds() >= timeframe.in_seconds('720') and timeframe.in_seconds() <= timeframe.in_seconds('5760')
```